How to modify the Windows Hyper-V interface/window (remove Actions pane)
I deleted Hyper-V as Windows Feature (Using "Turn Windows Features on or off") and then turned on again because I wanted to reset the layout of the Hyper-V user interface (I wanted to get rid of the "Actions" pane). This resulted in the removal of all my configured Virtual Switches but the Hyper-V windows still has the Actions column.
The Microsoft Management Console (mmc.exe) won't let me save the file "C:\Windows\System32\virtmgmt.msc". I changed the ownership and permissions of the file to give my user profile full access (instead of the default "TrustedInstaller") but that doesn't work. I tried creating a new profile for the MMC and save it with the modifications to Hyper-V but it won't let me save that profile either (message: MMC cannot save the profile). Any ideas? Please help.
